# How does shutter speed affect the video?

Tags: video, camera, filming

As shutter speed affects the coming light on sensor.But has it any affect on movement of subjects in video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things

1. The video gets brighter
2. The lower the shutter speed means more motion blur which makes it look more natural for the viewer

Answer (score 3):

A high shutter speed can make individual frames look more crisp but make large motion look like it is stuttering. e.g. fast panning looks like it is flickering or jumping

A low shutter speed can make individual frames look blurred and make the motion look smooth.

Answer (score 2):

A simple rule of thumb is to set shutter speed to double (x2) your project framerate.

EG: PAL project 25fps / Choose 50 shutter speed